# Confused about the number of independent components of the curvature tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, curvature

Supposedly the number of independent components of the [curvature tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor) is $n^2(n^2-1)/12$, where $n$ is the dimension. In the case of $n=2$ this evaluates to $1$, but if I take now for example
$$ds^2=R^2d\theta^2 + R^2\sin^2\theta d\phi^2,$$
where $R=const.$ one can show that the curvature tensor has the value
$$R^\theta_{\phi\theta\phi}=\sin^2\theta\quad \text{and}\quad R^\phi_{\theta\phi\theta}=1.$$
What exactly am I missing here?

Comment: I calculate $R_{\theta \theta \phi \phi}$ to be zero because the metric is diagonal.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I'm currently not at a desk, but I checked it before posting online and saw [this](https://mcgreevy.physics.ucsd.edu/f13/225A-pset06-sol.pdf).

Comment: In dimension $2$, only $R_{1221}$ matters. Everything else is zero or $\pm R_{1221}$. Indeed, there is $2^2(2^2-1)/12 = 1$ independent component. You have made a computation mistake somewhere.

Comment: I see, I should show my calculation to have you see where I went wrong. From wikipedia I got that $$R_{abcd} = K(g_{ac}g_{bd}-g_{ad}g_{bc})$$ and the $R_{aacc}$ vanishes either by that or the antisymmetries of the tensor.

Comment: @IvoTerek Does the $n^2(n^2-1)/12$ formula hold for $R_{abcd}$ and $R^{a}_{bcd}$?

Comment: @NinadMunshi Fair point. Can I assume then that $n^2(n^2-1)/12$ holds for $R^a_{bcd}$ and $R_{abcd}$? This seems a bit odd to me, since these two are certainly different...

Comment: Ivo is right  Furthermore $R$ is a tensor, that means its fundamental properties won't change with a coordinate transformation or what's effectively a fancy transpose.

Comment: @NinadMunshi My mistake, it should be $R^2_{121}$ instead of $R^1_{122}$. Using your formula I get
$$R_{2121} = K(g_{22}g_{11}-g_{21}g_{21}) = Kg_{22}g_{11} = KR^4\sin^2\theta\neq 0,$$
so $R^{2}_{121} = KR^2\neq 0$ and not proportional to $R^1_{212}$. Am I still missing something?

Comment: @IvoTerek See my previous comment. My question still remains: does the formula for the number of independent degrees hold for $R^a_{bcd}$ and $R_{abcd}$?

Comment: Of course it does, raising/lowering indices are isomorphisms between different tensor spaces.